# ILMerge OutOfMemoryException Error When Building Class Library

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, class-library, ilmerge

I'm new to C# Programming and I've been trying to build a DLL using ILMerge. I have never used it before, so this might be me not understanding how/what ILMerge is used for. In Visual Studio I have installed the following packages through NuGet:

- ILMerge v3.0.40
- ILMerge.MSBuild.Task v1.0.7

I started with something very simple:

```
using System;   
namespace My_Plugin
{
    public class Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

I am aware that using ILMerge for this is completely unncessary, but in the future, this class library will have references to other NuGet packages and I'd like to combine them into a single DLL file that I can distribute.

However, when I try to Build it in Release mode, I get the following error message:
"ILMerge.Merge:     There were errors reported in My Plugin's metadata.
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown"

Does this mean that I've misunderstood what ILMerge is and that it cannot be used with Class Libraries? If so, is there something else that I can use to merge a class library with its dependencies from NuGet into a single DLL that I can distribute?

Comment: Have you tried ILRepack?  I switched from ILMerge years ago, it was implemented to be basically a drop in replacement for ILMerge but without the bugs and slowness.

Comment: @BryceWagner Unfortunately, I'm very new to C#, so I do not have a lot of experience with these packages. Does ILRepack work in a similar way to ILMerge, in that I can install a NuGet package directly into Visual Studio and have it build a single executable when I build my project? I'm open to anything that gets the job done.

Comment: ILRepack and ILMerge are both command line executables, and ILRepack reproduced ILMerge command line parsing so they work identically.  However, I'm not familiar with the NuGet package usage for either one, so I don't know if there is are any significant differences there.  For my usage, I installed each one and then wrote post-build events to call the ILMerge/ILRepack.  I'm sure you can find instructions somewhere on how to use the ILRepack NuGet.